unity 2D spawn object with material
I am new in programing and I have a question , I have a folder with 2000 png images , I will spawn 2000 2D square sprites , each time an object spawn it should take one image as a sprite image  , I want to know how can I do that ? I am spawning that object only with one material because i am new programing , I don't know what is the best way to calculate each time one image attach to one spawn object.

You are going to need to iterate though and use Resource.Load().
Texture[] textures = new Texture[2000];
for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i ++) {
    // put textures into Assets/Resources/TextureFolder with names "texture0"..."texture2000"
    textures[i] = Resources.Load("TextureFolder/texture" + i.toString()) as Texture;
}


Thanks for your reply. So I made array and add all picture to array , So the problem happen after this . how to spawn object and attach one texture to that and of course I should control the texture should be use one time . sorry I am newbie

Why not simply reference them in a normal field in the Inspector? Not really a need for Resources here ...

because that images transfer from another pc , time by time to the resources folder or any folder , then the app should use them as a texture and spawn on screen

@Mehdi Assets in the resources folder are compiled when you build the game.  There is no Resources folder once you publish.  If you need to add assets after the game is released, look at addressables.
